# Stop addresses been recorded if already exists for customer

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I wanted to make my code record an address for a customer when making an order, I wanted this separate from shipping addresses. At the moment I'm struggling to figure out how to stop it continuously recorded the same address if the same customer places and order with the same address.

So to put it simply, if address already exists for customer do not add, if it does not exist add it.

**This is the view that records the address**

```
def process_order(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    
    

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, order_status='P')
       
    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == float(order.get_cart_total):
        order.order_status = 'C'
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            house=data['shipping']['house'],
            street=data['shipping']['street'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            postcode=data['shipping']['postcode'],
        )
        Address.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            house=data['shipping']['house'],
            street=data['shipping']['street'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            postcode=data['shipping']['postcode'],
        )
```

**MOdels**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Address(models.Model):
    house = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Username: %s - Name: %s %s' % ( self.customer.user ,self.customer.first_name, self.customer.last_name)
```

**screenshot of issue**

[image]

Comment: You already used `get_or_create` for orders, why not use it for address as well ?

Comment: would this not continue to create even if it existed?

Comment: Yes, get_or_create first tries to fetch the object, if doesn't exist the object is created and then fetched. see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for more info

Comment: Perfect thank you, embarrassingly I didn't realise this.

Comment: @Julkar9 would you like to post this as your answer and I will accept. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_or_create` instead of `create`.

`get_or_create` will try to fetch the record if it exists else a new instance will be created and returned.

Something like this

```
addrObj, created = Address.objects.get_or_create(
    customer=customer,
    house=data['shipping']['house'],
    street=data['shipping']['street'],
    city=data['shipping']['city'],
    postcode=data['shipping']['postcode'],
)
```

Link to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)